# requirejs + jquery plugins fires TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

**Generally a simple question.**

Why is it so always works:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'jquery': {exports: 'jQuery'},
        'jquery.plugin': { exports: 'jQuery', deps: ['jquery'] },
    },
});

define([
    'jquery.plugin'
], function($) {
    $('body').plugin();
});
```

and so the work is not always:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'jquery': {exports: 'jQuery'},
        'jquery.plugin': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    },
});

define([
    'jquery', 'jquery.plugin'
], function($) {
    $('body').plugin();
});
```

Periodically triggered error - "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'plugin'".

Exeperimently, i realized that the determination of the 'export' config parameter when the  method defines the key. And when you write:

```
define([
    'jquery', 'jquery.plugin'
], function(dep1, dep2) {
    ..
});
```

that dep1 not always === dep2 (but sometime O_o).

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score -1):

simply answer:

With jQuery in requirejs config parallel loading one more copy of another url jquery by YII Assets ( AppAsset::register($this) ) ...